# Django migration: `AlterUniqueTogether` fails with `constraint does not exist` but I think it's there

Tags: django

I'm trying to run the following migration using Django 2.2:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('actstream', '0002_remove_action_data'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='follow',
            name='flag',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, db_index=True, default='', max_length=255),
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='follow',
            unique_together=set([('user', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'flag')]),
        ),
    ]
```

The model **before** the git commit that adds the migration has the following constraint:

```py
unique_together = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

And **after** the git commit that adds the migration:

```py
unique_together = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'flag')
```

(`flag` is a new field and it's also been added to the `unique_together` constraint).

When I try to apply the migration, I get the following error message:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: constraint "actstream_follow_user_id_content_type_id_object_id" of relation "actstream_follow" does not exist
```

Inspecting my database as it is **without** the migration, tho, I see the following:

[image: The constraint seems to exist]

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of this:

[Django unable to migrate PostgreSQL: constraint X of relation Y does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585826/)

> The problem turned out to be that I converted the database to PostgreSQL from MySQL using the tool pgloader, and this tool converts constraints by creating them as indexes in PostgreSQL, whereas the Django PG backend creates them as constraints. So when the migration runs, it only looks for constraints and doesn't find any.

> I fixed this by dropping the index and re-creating it as a true constraint with:

```sql
drop index actstream_follow_user_id_content_type_id_object_id;
alter table actstream_follow add constraint actstream_follow_user_id_content_type_id_object_id unique(user_id, content_type_id, object_id);
```

Comment: If you feel it is a duplicate then why are you copying it here? Just mark your question as duplicate...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was an option. Will do now.